# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm just training cocos2d-x.
I tryed to show sprite animation,but EXC_BAD_ACCESS error showed.

I wrote code as follows.

However,when I wrote the "animation" function to the inside of "init" function ,EXC_BAD_ACCESS error didn't show.

What is wrong?

GameScene.h

```
 #include "cocos2d.h"
 #include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"


 class GameScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer
 {
  public:
  // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
  virtual bool init();

  // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
  static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();


  // implement the "static node()" method manually
  CREATE_FUNC(GameScene);

  void animation();


  cocos2d::CCSprite* pPlayer;

  //スプライトを格納する領域
  cocos2d::CCSpriteFrame* pSprites[12];

 };
```

GameScene.m

```
bool GameScene::init()
{
    if(!CCLayer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }



    //端末サイズ取得
CCSize visiblesize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();

//背景画像
CCSprite* bgImg = CCSprite::create("pic1.jpg");

//背景画像のポジション
bgImg->setPosition(ccp(visiblesize.width / 2, visiblesize.height / 2));
//背景画像のポジションを取得
CCPoint pos = bgImg->getPosition();




//===============================================================================
//                              ボタンイベント作成


//ボタンイベント追加
CCMenuItemImage *tapitem = CCMenuItemImage::create("animButton.png", "animButton.png", this, menu_selector(GameScene::animation));

CCMenu* tapMenu = CCMenu::create(tapitem, NULL);

tapMenu->setPosition(ccp(bgImg->convertToNodeSpace(pos).x, bgImg->convertToNodeSpace(pos).y));

//ボタン画像設置
bgImg->addChild(tapMenu);
//背景画像設置
this->addChild(bgImg);


cocos2d::CCSpriteFrame* pSprites[12];

const int WIDTH_SIZE = 96; //１つのスプライトの幅
const int HEIGHT_SIZE = 64; //１つのスプライトの高さ

//●アトラスから矩形切り出し、スプライト領域に格納.アニメーション画像を扱いたい時は、pSpriteから取り出してください。
for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        CCRect rect(x * WIDTH_SIZE, y * HEIGHT_SIZE,WIDTH_SIZE,HEIGHT_SIZE);
        pSprites[y * 3 + x] = CCSpriteFrame::create("texture1.png",rect);
    }
}



// プレイヤースプライトを生成
pPlayer= CCSprite::create("texture1.png", CCRectMake(0, 64, 96, 64));

// プレイヤーのポジション
pPlayer->setPosition(ccp(100,100));

//プレイヤーをシーンに登録して
bgImg->addChild(pPlayer);



return true;

}





void GameScene::animation()
{

//移動先の指定
CCMoveTo* move = CCMoveTo::create(1.8, ccp(200, 100));

//===============================================
//               アニメーションの作成
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::create();


for(int i=3;i<6;i++){
    animation->addSpriteFrame(pSprites[i]);
}

//アニメーションの設定：1コマ0.1秒で切り替える
animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.1);

//アニメーションの設定：６回ループさせる
animation->setLoops(6);


CCRepeatForever *pAction = CCRepeatForever::create( CCAnimate::create(animation) );

// 作成したアニメーションを実行
pPlayer->runAction(pAction);
pPlayer->runAction(move);

}
```

Comment: here is a [link](http://subhb.org/2012/07/02/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-error/) which would help to debug in EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Hope this is useful to you and if anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it didn't let me leave a comment as i don't have 50 rep... where exactly is this error coming up? The line i mean?

Is it this code piece?

```
for(int i=3;i<6;i++){
    animation->addSpriteFrame(pSprites[i]);
}
```

if yes, then please make sure that the "pSprites[i]" hasn't been released... If that is the case please create it with "new" and then perform a clean up by yourself.

The reason this could be happening is because there is no one referencing these sprites inside the "init" function... and when the flow comes out of "init" function, these values get released (as they are created with CREATE which sets autorelease by default)

Again, this is my assumption, looking at the code...
do give your feedback!

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.
YES! Its code pieces.
I have repaired as follows.

for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            pSprites[y * 3 + x]->release();

        }
}

then error ceases to show.But,the method that I repaired is long description.
For example,Are there not forms as follows?

pSprites = CCSpriteFrame::release();

But,when it is this form, I keep getting this error: "call to non-static member function without an object argument.

Comment: It is because you can call this method on a CCObject and since "pSprites" is an Array, you'll have to call Release on each of the values.

Comment: Also, release is a member function not a static function.
and it should be called like this,

>>>>> pSprites[i]->release(); // do it in a loop >>>>>>

Also, note that u should be careful about calling "release" on an "autorelease" object (An object created with "create" function is by default auto-release so you don't have to worry about it unless u want to explicitly delete it. As this object would be deleted once all references are removed)

Please mark this answer if it helped you!

Cheers!